# Synchronize folders between computers checking differences in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, git, sync, remote

I'm trying to synchronize a folder between my computer and my laptop. This sync should be bidirectional, because changes could be made in laptop or in computer. I would like it to check differences between files since last synchronization, so if an incompatibility appears, I could fix it and retry. Synchronization should be started with command line, so I could specify fastest route (IP).

Some approaches I thought is git, because git follows changes and can merge them, but I don't want to keep a history of changes, since the 'repository' is large (+150 GiB). I also found a tool based on git, called gut ([gut-sync](https://github.com/tillberg/gut)), which suits most of my requirements, but some problems appears. When I try to use it, output is:

```
ssh: must specify HostKeyCallback
```

This is because this package (gut) is old, and ssh from golang was updated. Following the code, I add HostKeyCallback in subpackage bismuth (same author of gut) (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269142/golang-ssh-getting-must-specify-hoskeycallback-error-despite-setting-it-to-n)).
After that, I try to sync folders again, it compiles some stuff (I don't know what is it) on remote machine, and it fails because of OpenSSL version (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837969/imap-send-c865-error-storage-size-of-hamc-isnt-known)). I don't want to have two OpenSSL versions on my system, so I would like to try other options.

What do you suggest? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at `rsync`. If file changed both on your computer and your laptop, how are you going to decide which version should be synced to? Because of this problem, "bidirectional sync" is difficult.

Comment: The idea is doing a manual merge when same file was changed on both devices. Because of rsync doesn't have a history from last sync, I think I can't use it.

Comment: If you want a "manual merge", you need at least one common ancestor to compare to against possible changes. Possibly on both computers. I don't know any ready-made application that does that, and isn't a full version-control system.

Comment: Yes, I need a common ancestor common to both computer and laptop, but Git would store all 'ancestors', and I only need the last one.

Comment: I found a tool named Unison, which helps me to synchronize both devices. It is fast, data is encrypted through network via SSH connection, and it is easy to use, so I recommend it.

Comment: BTW, you can also answer your own questions, and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for tools, including specific filesystems, git-based tools (git annex), and other tools, I found one named Unison, which allows me to synchronize two or more folders trough computers or locally, using a SSH client/server.

I tested Unison, and it is fast using a directory of more than 150 GiB. It can synchronize large files. I don't know how it works internally (using file time modification, differences, etc.

It allows you to merge files using your editor, but it requires some setup ([Unison on ArchLinux - Merging in Emacs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unison#Merging_in_Emacs)).

It requires Unison to be installed on both devices, and a SSH server on, at least, one of the devices.